# Getting the json file contents from form in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Scenario : I have the following HTML

```
<form action="http://example.com/nodejs/endpoint" 
      method="post" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>
        Select JSON file
        <input type="file" name="json">
    </label>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Requirement : i need to parse and display the uploaded json file in nodejs server.How do i get the file content from the request?

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that browser side or server side?

Comment: I need to parse the json on server side

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you to use express and express gen it would make a good skeleton for  your server, including json parser.